# Banco de dados embarcado com C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sqlite, firebird

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo local para *desktop*. Como não haverá servidores de banco de dados, estudei alguns, como o Firebird, SQLite, Access e até o Localdb. Mas ainda me sinto "perdido" em qual trabalhar. Sei que a escolha geral é SQLite, mas não me senti seguro quanto à segurança do mesmo, já que não oferece senhas para acessá-lo.

Não desejo um comparativo, mas apenas uma orientação de quem tem experiência. Lembrando novamente que o banco será local, não compartilhado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). É feito em java mas suporta c# tambem.

Comment: Vou ver sobre o HSQLDB. Agradeço a dica !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível criptografar e controlar o acesso pelo SQLite, não está pronto, você tem que fazer este processo, mas é factível.

Eu pensaria duas vezes antes de descartá-lo. Outras opções podem ter mais facilidades, mas se não souber o que está fazendo não terá segurança. Lembrando que se a pessoa tem acesso ao arquivo e existe uma senha de conhecimento de pessoas ou mesmo inserida na máquina de alguma forma, a segurança nunca será 100%.

Eu não usaria o MDB, mas dá para usar o SQL Server Compact (que já é legado, mas ainda suportado), ou o Firebird se gosta dele. Existe uma versão própria para trabalhar de forma embarcada, ela tem limitações mas acho que te atenderá.

O LocalDB é uma opção que funcionará bem e é mais adequada para quem está acostumado com o SQL Server. Claro que ele é bem mais pesado. Ele sai um pouco do que chamamos de banco de dados embarcado, não se caracteriza por ser um banco de dados para *desktop*, mas só você poderá dizer se é adequado para sua situação. Obviamente ele possui limitações do SQL Server Express, mas atende bem quase todas as situações de desktop, se aceitar o peso dele.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Como você sugeriu, fui mais a fundo sobre o SQLite e optei pelo mesmo. Agradeço pela orientação !