# Como criar um software em c# com banco de dados local?

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

Estou criando uma aplicação desktop, porém, ela não será para cliente, e sim para usuário. Ou seja, as pessoas irão baixar e instalar em suas casas. A questão principal é: como que eu faço para que esse sistema tenha um banco de dados que se instale automaticamente, e que se adapte a cada computador, independente do local que esteja. Preciso disso para testar o programa, usando um instalador etc. Li em vários lugares, várias perguntas, blogs, vídeos mas, a dúvida ainda permanece. Quem puder ajudar, agradeço desde já.

Comment: A pergunta não está tão clara, e principalmente é muito ampla, mas fechei como duplicata porque tem uma informação geral sobre o assunto. Se tiver úvidas mais específicas pode fazer. Tem outras que podem ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80849/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96689/101 .